# Creating a GUI using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a GUI using Tkinter. I got a basic outline but I need some help on how to actually have the entry boxes execute the numbers I enter into the box. I also need a box also on the Tkinter GUI that displays the final outcome.

What the GUI is all about: 
The GUI I am creating is just a feet to inches converter. It has an entry box for feet and an entry box for inches. The final `text` box is just inches. The code behind the final box should be converting the feet into inches and adding the inches the user has inputted into the GUI to get a sum of the final.

Example:
For example 5 feet and 8 inches will equal 68 inches.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import tkinter as tk

fields = ('Feet', 'Inches')


def feet(entries):
    feet = 1


def converter(entries):
    feet = 1
    inches = 12
    final = feet/12 + inches
    return final


def makeform(root, fields):
    entries = {}
    for field in fields:
        print(field)
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=22, text=field + ": ", anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        ent.insert(0, "0")
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP,
                 fill=tk.X,
                 padx=5,
                 pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,
                 expand=tk.YES,
                 fill=tk.X)
        entries[field] = ent
    return entries


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    ents = makeform(root, fields)
    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Convert',
                   command=(lambda e=ents: feet(e)))
    b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
    b2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```

What I need help with:
I need help creating just a simple text box that says "Inches:" and it displays the final sum of the feet being converted into inches added to the inches the user has inputted into the interface.
Example: 
`Inches: (final sum)`
I also need a centered text box at the top middle of the actual GUI it self saying "Feet to inches converter"

Current problem:
As of what I know, the code that executes will prompt the GUI, but when I enter any numbers into the feet or inches entries nothing happens. Inside of the Pycharm terminal the following shows up. 

`Feet: 
Inches:`
 
I don't know why that happens but I just know that when I input my feet and inches nothing further is executed.

Here is also a sample of what the GUI could look like:
[image: Example GUI output]

Comment: Do `print(entries)` inside `def converter(entries):` and see what you get.

Comment: your button runs `feet()` but not `converter()`. And you don't get values from entries - `ents['Feet'].get()` `ents['Inches'].get()`

Answer (score 1):

First: button should execute `converter()`, not `feet()`

```
command=(lambda e=ents: converter(e))
```

Second: in `converter()` you have to get values from entries and convert to int

```
feet = int( entries['Feet'].get() )
inches = int( entries['Inches'].get() )
```

Third: at start you should create `Label` even without text and late `converter()` will have to change text in this `Label`

```
label['text'] = 'Result: {}'.format(final)
```

And last: in calculation you have to use `*`, not `/`

```
final = feet*12 + inches
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk

fields = ('Feet', 'Inches')

def converter(entries):
    feet = int( entries['Feet'].get() )
    inches = int(  entries['Inches'].get() )
    final = feet*12 + inches
    label['text'] = 'Result: {}'.format(final)

def makeform(root, fields):
    entries = {}
    for field in fields:
        print(field)
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=22, text=field + ": ", anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        ent.insert(0, "0")
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP,
                 fill=tk.X,
                 padx=5,
                 pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,
                 expand=tk.YES,
                 fill=tk.X)
        entries[field] = ent
    return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    ents = makeform(root, fields)

    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Convert',
                   command=(lambda e=ents:converter(e)))
    b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

    b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
    b2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

    label = tk.Label(root, text='Result: 0')
    label.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```